# Bar graph color dependent on value in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a bar graph, as follows:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#self.Data1 is an array containing all the data points, inherited from a separate class

DataSet = range(46)
self.Figure1 = plt.figure()
self.Figure1.patch.set_alpha(0)
self.Canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.Figure1)

#Add canvas to pre-existing Widget#
self.Widget.addWidget(self.Canvas1)
self.Ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='black')
self.Ax1.bar(DataSet, self.Data1, width=1, color='r')
self.Ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
plt.title('GRAPH TITLE', color='w', fontsize=30, fontname='Sans Serif', fontweight='bold')
self.Figure1.tight_layout()
```

This is working nicely, producing the following graph:

[image: Current graph]

What I'd like to do is set the bar color depending on the value. I.e. blue if the value is positive and red if the value is negative. What's the easiest way to do so? Do I need to create a Color Map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by far not the best solution in terms of reusability and/or scalability, but if you only want to have red bars for negative numbers and blue bars for positive number, you can call the barplot twice, by filtering the values before hand. Here is a minimal example of what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

array = np.random.randn(100)
greater_than_zero = array > 0
lesser_than_zero = array < 0
cax = pl.subplot(111)
cax.bar(np.arange(len(array))[greater_than_zero], array[greater_than_zero], color='b')
cax.bar(np.arange(len(array))[lesser_than_zero], array[lesser_than_zero], color='r')
```

[result http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/547091download.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/547091download.png)

Comment: Thanks for that Challensois. My application is already calling several other plots, so ideally I'd like to implement a single plot, but this is a great alternative if I'm unable to.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'a single plot'. I edited my answer to show you that you can plot on the same subplot `cax`. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: My apologies, I got myself a little confused there. Your edit makes it more clear, thanks for that. I'll give it a go now.

Answer (score 11):

You can also specify an arraylike as the color kwarg as such:

```
x = np.arange(1,100)
y = np.sin(np.arange(1,100))
colors = np.array([(1,0,0)]*len(y))
colors[y >= 0] = (0,0,1)
plt.bar(x,y,color = colors)
```

So long as colors is the same length as y, you can specify the colors however you want.

[image]

Or for something a little fancier:

```
x = np.arange(1,100)
y = np.sin(3*np.arange(1,100))
colors = np.array([(1,0,0)]*len(y))
colors[y >= 0] = (0,0,1)
mult = np.reshape(np.repeat(np.abs(y)/np.max(np.abs(y)),3),(len(y),3))
colors =  mult*colors
plt.bar(x,y,color = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Even better than the solution I suggested! This `np.array([(1,0,0)]*len(y))` is really neat!

Comment: Really nice csunday95! Thank you for your contribution!